# Checking how many times a document has been read in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a video based app that keeps track of how many views that video has received. I originally planned on having a field for view_count in my document that I would write to after someone watches a video.

However, knowing how many writes that could end up leading to, I started to wonder if it's possible to see a breakdown of how many reads have been made for each document in a collection and use that number instead. Since the videos are short, I figured this would be an accurate number for the view count.

Is this possible to access this kind of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore does not expose any per-document access metrics. The available monitoring options are shown on this page on [monitoring usage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage).

If you want something beyond that you'll have to build it yourself, as you originally intended.